# why throw me this error when i try to show my api from django data in react "products undefined". In the console show me the data but not show

Tags: reactjs, django

> `import logo from '../logo.svg';
> import SingleProduct from './SingleProduct'
> import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
> function AllProducts() {
> const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
>
> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>     fetchData('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/');
> });
>
> function fetchData(baseurl) {
>     fetch(baseurl)
>         .then((response) => response.json())
>         .then((data) => setProducts(data.results));
>
> }
>
>
> return (
>
>     <section className="container mt-4" >
>         {/* Latest Products */}
>         <h3 className="mb-4">All Products</h3>
>         <div className="row mb-4" >
>             {
>                 products.map((product) => <SingleProduct product={product} />)
>             }
>
>
>
>         </div>
>         <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
>             <ul className="pagination">
>                 <li className="page-item"><a className="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
>                 <li className="page-item"><a className="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
>                 <li className="page-item"><a className="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
>                 <li className="page-item"><a className="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
>                 <li className="page-item"><a className="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
>             </ul>
>         </nav>
>     </section>
>
>
> )
> ```
>
> }
>
> export default AllProducts;`